# Owncloud Client for Linux automatic login

Tags: owncloud

I have a server with an Owncloud installation, and I have some scripts that import photos from my SLR camera, scales them, lowers the quality and puts them into the Owncloud directory which then gets synced to the server, and then I have access to the photos on my smartphone.

The "issue" I have is that the Owncloud client on Linux (2.1.1) requires the password to be entered before it starts. This causes problems for me because the file syncs to the remote server are no longer automatic after I start my computer. I've found no way to enter the password via the CLI, nor does the documentation state there is a password to be passed in `$HOME/.local/share/data/ownCloud/owncloud.cfg`.

I looked into `owncloudcmd`, where you can pass the username/password via the commandline, however it has to go through the entire collection to see what needs to be uploaded, or synced, which takes well over a minute. I would prefer to somehow autologin into my account via the regular client since it seems that it has a nicer sync mechanism as it has a sense what's already been synced and what hasn't.

I guess the `owncloudcmd` thing is an option to think about, placing it in cron every 15 minutes or so to run, but it seems wasteful.